# pushed value in dataLayer shows undefined in GTM admin

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I get the "user-profile-name" variable from GTM, then encrypt it and push it to the dataLayer to use it in GA later.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>

<script>

  function generateHash(str) {

    var domain = window.location.hostname;

    var hashedString = CryptoJS.MD5(str+domain).toString();

    return hashedString;

  }     
  var userEmail = {{user-profile-name}};

  if (userEmail) {

    var hashedEmail = generateHash(userEmail);

    dataLayer.push({'user_id': hashedEmail});

  }

</script>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMHTT.png)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSZnR.png)

The resulting variable is displayed only in the "Message" section, in the other sections it is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please read this question and the accepted response:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74052768/why-datalayer-push-does-not-send-info-to-google-analytics-data-api-ga4